# Store read memory process in a buffer then search it

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I want to read the memory from a process for 16 MB (FFFFFF) and store it in a array, in a way that when I search inside the array like: array[i], i will be the real memory address.

Lets say I want to search from 000000 to FFFFFF, I want to make that jump sizeof(value), get the address from that address and store it in a var.

then if(var==value) return address.

i have this:
ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,buffer,0xFFFFFF,0);

EDIT:

i have this (by BlueWanderer answer):

> ```
> class offset_buffer{
> private:
>         char *buf;
>         int offset;
>
> public:
>         offset_buffer(char *in_buf, int in_offset)
>                 : buf(in_buf), offset(in_offset){
>         }
>
>         char & operator[](int in_index){
>                 return buf[in_index - offset];
>         }
>
>         void setOffset(int off){
>                 offset=off;
>         }
>
>         void ReadMemory(){
>                 LPBYTE point;
>                 DWORD primeiroAddress = 0x000000;
>                 DWORD finalAddress = 0xFFFFFF;
>                 //LPBYTE buffer = new BYTE[finalAddress-primeiroAddress];
>                 HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,0,TargetPID);
>                 ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)primeiroAddress, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
>                 CloseHandle(phandle);
>         }
> };
>
> main(){
> char *buffer = new char[0xFFFFFFF-0x0000000];
> int address = 0x0000000;
> offset_buffer b(buffer,address);
> std::ostringstream ss;
> int i=0;
> TListItem *ListIt;
> b.ReadMemory();
> for(address=0x0000000;address<0xFFFFFFF;address+=sizeof(int)){
>         if(b[address]==StrToInt(Edit1->Text.c_str())){
>                  ss << std::hex << address;
>                  showValue();
>                  ss.str(std::string());
>         }
> }
> ```

what is wrong?? can someone help me? why it doesn't work

Comment: that what? it would work but i don't know the type i have to use, can you send me a code especifying it?

Comment: What do you mean by "i will be the real memory address"? If you're trying to find a specific address in the other process, you'll need to compensate for the difference between the base address of that 16 meg in your process vs. the other. `offset = address - their_base; whatever *var = (whatever *)(our_base + offset);`

Comment: the counter i would be the real memory address.
like i know the address 0C2F8E3 has value 50 and typeint, so if i do buffer[0C2F8E3] i will get the value 50

Comment: just edited, with BlueWanderer answer changed

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this?

```
class offset_buffer
{
private: 
    char *buf;
    int offset;

public:
    offset_buffer(char *in_buf, int in_offset)
        : buf(in_buf), offset(in_offset)
    {
    }

    char & operator[](int in_index)
    {
        return buf[in_index - offset];
    }
};
```

It will map your `real address` to the index in the array

```
offset_buffer b(buffer, address);

if (b[0x0C2F8E3] == 123) return 0x0C2F8E3;
```

Comment: what would be the offset? who do i use that?